# Golang append slice to a slice of slice, then the slice will always affect the slice of slice?

Tags: go, append, slice

Today I got this code:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var results [][]int
    combination := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    results = append(results, combination)
    fmt.Println(results)

    combination2 := combination[:len(combination)-1]
    combination2 = append(combination2, 0)
    fmt.Println(results)

}
```

the output shows :

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]]
[[1 2 3 4 0]]
```

so why the results been affected? I cannot find any reason, and it puzzled me a lot, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `result` isn't directly affected, but `combination` is (or, rather, its underlying array).

You "slice" `combination` to get `combination2`. Their underlying array is the same.

Now when you do the append operation you basically say "after this slice ends I want element `0`". By doing this you also change the last element of the first slice to be `0`.

Check out this example: https://play.golang.org/p/m0bPJDj9kHs

P.S. You can prevent this by using `copy()` operation.

Comment: thank you very much!  the copy() function solved this!